# Add Sharepoint Group as Group Owner

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, groups

I am trying to add a SharePoint Group as a Group Owner to another SharePoint Group using CSOM but unfortunately I am not successful.  Please find my script below. Can someone please suggest where I might be going wrong?

```
$var="Project Owners";
        $groupOwner = $ctx.Web.SiteGroups[$var]
        $ctx.Load($groupOwner)
        $OneNoteGroup.Owner = $groupOwner
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    ctx.Credentials = credentials;

    var groupCreationInfo = new GroupCreationInformation
    {
         Title = groupName,
         Description = groupDesc
    };

    var groupOwner = ctx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Tech Support"); //get an existing group

    var group = ctx.Web.SiteGroups.Add(groupCreationInfo);
    group.Owner = groupOwner;
    group.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();     
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653909/how-to-add-a-sharepoint-group-as-group-owner-with-client-object-model